# Hybrid Cloud and Azure subscriptions and resource groups

Tags: azure, cloud, hybrid-cloud

I have got some questions regarding cloud best practices:

1. Can I put in an Azure Subscription, objects coming from different regions? eg. North Europe, West Europe...
2. Can a subscription span multiple clouds? E.g.: Azure, Amazon...
3. Can an Azure resource group contain objects from different regions?
4. Can a Resource Group span multiple clouds? E.g.: Azure, Amazon...

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can have resources from multiple regions in an Azure subscription, but it is up to you if you want to segregate subscriptions based on region or not. I personally segregate subscriptions based on environments (dev, qa, prod).
2. No, Azure subscriptions are for resources only in Azure.
3. No, resource groups should only contain resources from the same region as that resource group. Resource groups should only contain resources that share the same lifecycle and should be updated/deleted all together.
4. No, same as subscriptions, Azure only.

Comment: Not true for #3. Resource groups are merely an organizational and security boundary. There is no such rule that you need to limit objects in a resource group to a single region (and this idea will immediately break down when you try deploying a multi-region service such as Cosmos DB). Further: the region of the *resource group* itself has nothing to do with the region of the objects *inside* the resource group. This doesn't matter at all.

Comment: And resource group objects don't necessarily need to share the same lifecycle. There might be advantages (such as being able to delete all resources at once by deleting the resource group), but how you use a resource group is really up to the people working on the project.

Comment: I dont buy the same lifecycle story. in real world applications are not what they are in the text book. this is somewhat hard to achieve with no real gain.